# GIS proj pipeline

Tags: qgis, proj

I would like to create a custom projection in QGIS 3.10.
It is a local stereo and the reprojection between WGS84 and the local stereo uses proj pipeline. For example in cs2cs it is (which works well):

```
cs2cs +proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +to +proj=pipeline +step +proj=stere
+lat_0=46.57668421 +lon_0=18.85441407 +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=helmert
+convention=coordinate_frame +x=1395.698 +y=11825.906 +s=1.000023273
+theta=521 -r -f "%.3f"
```

In QGIS adding the following proj definition I get illegal definition:

```
+proj=pipeline +step +proj=stere
    +lat_0=46.57668421 +lon_0=18.85441407 +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=helmert
    +convention=coordinate_frame +x=1395.698 +y=11825.906 +s=1.000023273
    +theta=521
```

How should I give the definition for QGIS? QGIS uses proj 6.